Re-installing a package
Why do I have to re-install a package all over again? When I tried to run code, it returns an error until I install the specific package again. What could be the problem?
Below shows the problem, I had to install 'tidyr' again for it to run.
newtable4a <- pivot_longer(table4a, 2:3,  names_to = "year", values_to = "cases")


Fehler in pivot_longer(table4a, 2:3, names_to = "year", values_to = "cases") :
konnte Funktion "pivot_longer" nicht finden

I expected that if the package was already installed, then the pivot_longer() function would run as there was no need for me to re-install tidyr again.

You need to load packages at the beginning of each session prior to running any associated functions. So run library(tidyr) first, then run your code to see if that solves your issue.

When writing every code, be sure to use the library() function. Each .r file is working in the base form. For example, if you start a new r script it should be run this way:
library(tidyr)
newtable4a <- pivot_longer(table4a, 2:3,  names_to = "year", values_to = "cases")

Without doing this, R is working in the base form. It's also a good idea to re-install packages from time to time because they do update.
